# How to iterate vm_area in bpf/bcc program?

Tags: python, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I am trying to iterate over `vm_area_struct` whenever the user space program calls the function `hello`. How to do so?

`mm->mmap` is not available anymore. We need to iterate the maple tree `mm_mt`. But `for_each_vma` is not working with error shown below.

I want to ultimately be able to copy one of the vm_area pages but I am stuck at a step prior to that. Mentioning this in case it's an X/Y Problem.

My code:

```
from bcc import BPF

bpf_text = r"""
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>

int hello_enter(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    bpf_trace_printk("Hello\n");
    struct task_struct *ts = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
    bpf_trace_printk("%u\n", ts->pid);

    struct mm_struct *mm = ts->mm;
    if (mm) {
        struct vm_area_struct *vma;
        VMA_ITERATOR(iter, mm, 0);

        for_each_vma(iter, vma) {
            //virt_size += vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
            //bpf_trace_printk("%lx\t%lx", vma->vm_start, vma->vm_end);
        }
    } else {
        bpf_trace_printk("No memory management structure (mm) found\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
"""

# Load BPF program
b = BPF(text=bpf_text)

# Attach uprobe
b.attach_uprobe(name="./test.out", sym="hello", fn_name="hello_enter")

# Print traced messages
b.trace_print()
```

Error:

```
sudo python as2.py 
In file included from /virtual/main.c:2:
In file included from include/uapi/linux/ptrace.h:183:
In file included from arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:5:
In file included from arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h:7:
arch/x86/include/asm/ibt.h:77:8: warning: 'nocf_check' attribute ignored; use -fcf-protection to enable the attribute [-Wignored-attributes]
extern __noendbr u64 ibt_save(bool disable);
       ^
arch/x86/include/asm/ibt.h:32:34: note: expanded from macro '__noendbr'
#define __noendbr       __attribute__((nocf_check))
                                       ^
arch/x86/include/asm/ibt.h:78:8: warning: 'nocf_check' attribute ignored; use -fcf-protection to enable the attribute [-Wignored-attributes]
extern __noendbr void ibt_restore(u64 save);
       ^
arch/x86/include/asm/ibt.h:32:34: note: expanded from macro '__noendbr'
#define __noendbr       __attribute__((nocf_check))
                                       ^
2 warnings generated.
bpf: Failed to load program: Invalid argument
jump out of range from insn 41 to 58
processed 0 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/veracrypt3/projects/ebpf/as2.py", line 39, in <module>
    b.attach_uprobe(name="./test.out", sym="hello", fn_name="hello_enter")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 1383, in attach_uprobe
    fn = self.load_func(fn_name, BPF.KPROBE)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 526, in load_func
    raise Exception("Failed to load BPF program %s: %s" %
Exception: Failed to load BPF program b'hello_enter': Invalid argument
```